# Apache ReWrite Condition Thinks A Directory Isn't a Directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-10.04

On my server (Apache2, Ubuntu 10.04), `wpsa` is a directory in my webroot. When accessing the url mysite.com/wpsa, a ReWriteRule which should not occur when the requested file is a directory, runs anyway.

These are my rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /000_ROUTE.php [L]
```

This is from the rewrite log:

```
applying pattern '.*' to uri '/wpsa/'
RewriteCond: input='/wpsa/' pattern='!^/index.php$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/wpsa/' pattern='!^/$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/wpsa/' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/wpsa/' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite '/wpsa/' -> '/000_ROUTE.php'
local path result: /000_ROUTE.php
```

It says, "Is 'wpsa' a driectory?" -> "No it's not". But really it is. Why does it think my directory isn't a directory?

If I add:

```
ReWriteRule ^/wpsa - [L,NC]
```

before this rule, it loads the directory. But I shouldn't have to create a rule that does nothing for every directory, should I? That's what the -f/-d conditions are for.

Answer (score 2):

Your webroot isn't `/` (right?), so it's correct that `-d` didn't get a hit.  It's trying to match `/wpsa/` to the filesystem, literally - not relative to the webroot.

The reason it's giving you `/wpsa/` as your string input instead of `/path/to/webroot/wpsa`, which would work as expected, is that you're using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in the wrong context.

When `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is used in a context where the filesystem mapping is already done, like in a `<Directory>` block or `.htaccess` file, the full path is returned and `-d` will work as you're expecting.

[From the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> REQUEST_FILENAME
>
> The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI.

You seem to be using it in a `<VirtualHost>` or `<Location>` context, which makes it functionally identical to `%{REQUEST_URI}`.  If you'd like to keep it in that context, try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
```

Comment: +1, good explanation. I'm going to try this out when I get back later and accept. I guess I assumed that starting with a forward slash meant the web-root in this context too since it does in rewrite rules, etc. And you're correct, this is in the vhost not .htaccess.